# Why $|z_1z_2|^2 = |z_1|^2|z_2|^2$ implies $|z_1z_2| = |z_1||z_2|$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I have this proof and I couldn't comprehend the final result. I do understand the steps though but why $|z_1z_2|^2 = |z_1|^2|z_2|^2 \implies |z_1z_2| = |z_1||z_2|$. The vise verse is lucid to me

> For any two complex numbers, $z_1$ and $z_2$  $$ |z_1 z_2| = |z_1||z_2| $$
> **Proof:**
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> |z_1 z_2|^2 &= (z_1z_2)\overline{(z_1z_2)} \\ &= z_1z_2\overline{z}_1\overline{z}_2 \\
> &= z_1\overline{z}_1z_2\overline{z}_2 \\ &= |z_1|^2|z_2|^2
> \end{align*}
> $$
> From this it follows that
> $$
> |z_1 z_2| = |z_1||z_2| \qquad \text{QED}
> $$

Comment: All of the moduli are positive real numbers, so simply take the square root of both sides

Comment: If $a,b$ are real numbers with $a,b \ge 0$, then we have $a^2=b^2 \iff a=b.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Stephen Donovan's comment, all of the moduli are positive real number which negates $\pm$ from resulting when you square root. Continuing from the proof:
$$\therefore \sqrt{|z_{1}z_{2}|^{2}} = \sqrt{|z_{1}|^{2}|z_{2}|^{2}}$$
$$|\pm z_{1}z_{2}| = |\pm z_{1}|^{2*0.5}|\pm z_{2}|^{2*0.5}$$
$$|z_{1}z_{2}|=|\pm z_{1}||\pm z_{2}|$$
$$|z_{1}z_{2}|=|z_{1}||z_{2}|$$